# How to scroll left or right inside a div using pure javascript function and no jquery?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to scroll left or right inside a div using javascript alone and no jquery for a purpose. I have achieved it using jquery but I need to do it using javascript alone. Code:-

I want the buttons to help scroll horizontally along the div left or right.How to do it. I achieved it using jquery this way:-

```js
$('#right-button').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=200px"
  }, "slow");
});

 $('#left-button').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=200px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.inner {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.paddle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
}

.lefty {
  left: 0;
}

.righty {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer" id="content">
 <button class="lefty paddle" id="left-button"></button>
  <div class="inner" style="background:red"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background:green"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background:blue"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background:yellow"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background:orange"></div>
 <button class="righty paddle" id="right-button"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: You're not just scrolling, you are animating. Do you want to keep it in vanilla javascript too ?

Comment: the jquery code works ....yea I want to keep the animation too maybe...if it doesnt cause much difficulty...basically I just want to scroll left or right using the buttons

Comment: Well maybe the jQuery code works. Hard to tell with the errors it throws. Mind putting up some working code?

Comment: how to just scroll without animation even that will do

Comment: FYI: `event.preventDefault();` isn't needed in the JQuery or JavaScript solution because `button` elements don't have any native/default behavior to cancel.

Answer (score 13):

You just need to use `translateX` as following:
Also, I extremely recommend you to not use js for animate simple things like this.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const lefty = document.querySelector(".lefty");
let translate = 0;

lefty.addEventListener("click", function() {
   translate += 200;
   container.style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "px" + ")";
});

const righty = document.querySelector(".righty");
righty.addEventListener("click", function() {
   translate -= 200;
   container.style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "px" + ")";
});
```

```css
.outer {
  
  overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: hidden;

}

.container {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform .4s ease-in;
}

.inner {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  height: 100px;
 margin:10px;
}
.paddle {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 30px;
 height:20px;
}
.lefty {
 left: 0;
  z-index:1;
}
.righty{
 right: 0;
   z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<button class="lefty paddle" id="left-button"></button>
<div class="outer" id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner" style="background:red"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:green"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:blue"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:yellow"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:orange"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="righty paddle" id="right-button"></button>
```

Comment: how do you stop from scrolling past the end?

Answer (score 7):

Use [`scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) to scroll an element:

```js
var content = document.getElementById('content'),
    scrollStep = 200;

document.getElementById('right-button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let sl = content.scrollLeft,
      cw = content.scrollWidth;
 
  if ((sl + scrollStep) >= cw) {
    content.scrollTo(cw, 0);
  } else {
    content.scrollTo((sl + scrollStep), 0);
  }
});

document.getElementById('left-button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let sl = content.scrollLeft;
 
  if ((sl - scrollStep) <= 0) {
    content.scrollTo(0, 0);
  } else {
    content.scrollTo((sl - scrollStep), 0);
  }
});
```

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.inner {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  height: 100px;
  margin:10px;
}
.paddle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height:20px;
}
.lefty {
  left: 0;
}
.righty{
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" id="content">
  <button class="lefty paddle" id="left-button"></button>
  <div class="inner" style="background:red"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background:green"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background:blue"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background:yellow"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background:orange"></div>
  <button class="righty paddle" id="right-button"></button>
</div>
```

It turns out that MS Edge and IE doesn't supports `scrollTo()` method.

Comment: "Check this" isn't really a good answer. Answers should include explanations of what they are doing and why. Also, there is no animation in this solution, which the OP currently does have.

Comment: @ScottMarcus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611362/how-to-scroll-left-or-right-inside-a-div-using-pure-javascript-function-and-no-j/50611684#comment88233067_50611362

Comment: That is just a link to this answer?!

Comment: @ScottMarcus nope, it is a link to a comment where OP says *"how to just scroll without animation even that will do"*. Anyway, added an *explanation* in the question.

Comment: Remember that answers on Stack Overflow aren't just for the OP. Stack Overflow is a knowledge base for future visitors to get answers from. And, a simple link to documentation is not the same thing as an explanation of what your code does.

Comment: @ScottMarcus my friend, there isn't much to explain there, it is a very simple code. You will have to go out there down voting tons of similar - but with good quality - posts then...

Comment: Well, my friend, you and I have different ideas of what a "good quality" post is. Let me ask you this, what are `scrollLeft` and `scrollRight`? What do they return? Can they be trusted to work correctly cross-browser? And, why did you keep `e.preventDefault()` in your solution?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I kept the `preventDefault` because it was present on the original OP's code. I'm not sure why he added it but it could be for preventing a form submission as it is not defined as `type="button"`. Also, if I have to explain every keyword in the code, I would have to begin explaining what `var` stands for, `document`, `getElementById`, `addEventListener` and so on... I'm not here to perform a full JS course.

Comment: You are introducing a solution and using new DOM methods that the OP clearly doesn't know about, but not providing any explanation for them. No one is asking you to provide explanations for the code that is already there. But, you never know what level of experience the OP has or what level future readers of this whole post will have and that's why answers need explanations to be "good quality". Also, you don't think it might be worth warning the OP that `scrollLeft` and `scrollRight` might not work correctly all the time and why if you're going to present them as solutions?

Comment: @ScottMarcus As I said, it is a very simple code, very basic. Some effort from who's viewing it to understand is required, I think. About `scrollLeft` and `scrollRight` might not work correctly all the time, it is beyond my knowledge, I thought it would be a good solution, I can be wrong of course...

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Thanks for the conditions, I took the benefit.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution using core javascript for custom horizontal scroll

In .html

```html
<div class="pull-left mt-sm">
    <i class="icon-arrow-left pointer" onclick="scrollLeft()"></i>
</div>   
       
<div #widgetsContent class="custom-slider-main">
    <div class="info-box">
        <img src="file.jpg" class="info-box">
    </div>
    <div class="info-box">
        <img src="file.jpg" class="info-box">
    </div>
    <div class="info-box">
        <img src="file.jpg" class="info-box">
    </div>
    <div class="info-box">
        <img src="file.jpg" class="info-box">
    </div>
    <div class="info-box">
        <img src="file.jpg" class="info-box">
    </div>
    <div class="info-box">
        <img src="file.jpg" class="info-box">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="pull-right mt-sm">
    <i class="icon-arrow-right pointer" onclick="scrollRight()"></i>
</div>
```

In .css

```css
.custom-slider-main{
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;    
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.info-box{
    width: 50px;
    height:50px
}
```

In .js

```js
let widgetsContent = document.getElementById("widgetsContent")
```

And On click of left/right button use the following functions

```js
scrollLeft(){
    widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollLeft -= 150;
}
   
scrollRight(){
    widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollLeft += 150;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use this for just the scrolling but the animation would be separate.

```
document.getElementById("right-button").addEventListener("click", function() 
{
  $('#content').animate({ scrollLeft: "+=200px" }, "slow");
});

document.getElementById("left-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  $('#content').animate({ scrollLeft: "-=200px" }, "slow");
});
```